# Ubuntu 18 Point two domains to same folder

Tags: apache, virtualhost, ubuntu-18.04

I've a server installed with Ubuntu 18.04 and on that server I've created new host for a new sub-domain:

**api.example.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias api.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/searchcore
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I would like now to add another sub-domain "**newapi.example.com**" and I would like it to point to the same folder of the first domain (/var/www/searchcore).

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *ServerAlias* directive accepts one or more names, so you can simply append the name of your new sub-domain to the existing *ServerAlias* directive like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias api.example.com newapi.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/searchcore
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Alternatively, you can also have multiple *ServerAlias* directives:

```
    ...    
    ServerAlias api.example.com
    ServerAlias new.example.com
    ...
```

You might want to check out the docs here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias